# User Defined Type change

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2, user-defined-types

I want to implement a user defined type (table) in SQL Server (2008 R2) that is passed from a VB.NET application.  This will be a generic type used in place of passing comma-delimited lists (at least initially it will be exclusively ID values).

If it is decided later that we need to modify the UDT, will we also need to change everywhere in the application code that we attempt to use the UDT?  Or can we get around having to do such a thing by making a new column in the UDT nullable?

The concern is that if we want to add a new column to the table we will need to go back and change all the places this UDT is used in the application, whether those places will need the new column or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add columns to the UDT as long as they DO allow NULL values.

As far as the application code, it will depend on what you are calling.  If you want to add data to the new column, you will need to change the code where you are inserting rows.  If you are retrieving the data, you will need to change the code to get the data from the new column.

Are you asking if changing the UDT on the server side will require immediate changes to your code?  You should not need to.  SELECT queries in VB require you to access each column specifically after each query so additional columns should not affect the code.  Same with inserting rows: if you are using cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO table (field1, [field2, ... ]) VALUES (value1, [value2, ...])" then each column is specifically labeled and additional columns should not affect the application unless the no not allow NULL.

Comment: I will clarify the question, but the intent is that this will be used for passing lists to stored procedures, rather than sending comma-delimited lists or making multiple DB calls for a single atomic operation.  So, ultimately, this UDT will only ever be used as an input parameter to various stored procedures, and the concern is if we later need to add a column we will need to modify everywhere the parameter is used.

Comment: You should be able to modify the stored procedure to add the additional column to the input. 'SELECT *, 'newdata' AS NewCol FROM inputTable

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work.  Changing the type breaks the code.  I have found a solution in which when creating the table you query the type and add any extra columns, though.

Comment: What type are you changing?

Comment: The User Defined Table Type that I created to pass in as a table-valued parameter to a stored procedure.

Comment: You do not need to change this to add a new column.  I think we are saying the same thing.  Good luck moving forward!